# How to correctly setup RUTA config parameters in the script?

Tags: ruta

Help is needed with a code example for proper understanding of setting parameters in own RUTA script.

In my case I need to setup the configuration parameter "emptyIsInvisible" to false. The root cause is described in [Are some extra settings in RUTA script needed to detect annotations with the same begin and end attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468812/are-some-extra-settings-in-ruta-script-needed-to-detect-annotations-with-the-sam)

I made two attempts

1) use the name of standard Ruta Engine:

```
ENGINE BasicEngine; 
Document{->CONFIGURE(BasicEngine, "emptyIsInvisible" = false)};`
```

That part of the script does not change the default settings.

2) use the name of own engine:

```
ENGINE xxx.yyy.zzz.TagEngine;
Document{->CONFIGURE(TagEngine, "emptyIsInvisible" = false)};
```

In that case the script raises the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1081)
at      sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1048)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:226)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:236)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:589)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:587)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:586)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:611)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.uima.internal.util.XMLUtils.createSAXParserFactory(XMLUtils.java:543)
at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parse(XMLParser_impl.java:159)
at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseResourceSpecifier(XMLParser_impl.java:399)
at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseResourceSpecifier(XMLParser_impl.java:381)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:278)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:270)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeEngines(RutaEngine.java:896)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeScript(RutaEngine.java:820)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:527)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:267)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:172)
at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:270)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeEngines(RutaEngine.java:896)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeScript(RutaEngine.java:820)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:527)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:267)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:172)
at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:270)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeEngines(RutaEngine.java:896)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeScript(RutaEngine.java:820)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:527)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:267)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:172)
at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.Ruta.wrapAnalysisEngine(Ruta.java:270)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeEngines(RutaEngine.java:896)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeScript(RutaEngine.java:820)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:527)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:267)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:172)
at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This parameter will not solve the problems in the linked question. The parameter controls the basic matching if there are no annotations at all at some positions. This means that is will only affect the matching if a different seeding is applied, e.g., there is no seeding.

Concerning this question: 
You cannot configure the RutaEngine analysis engine within the script the analysis engine tries to execute. You need to set the configuration parameter on framework level. This depends on how you create and run the UIMA analysis engines in your code.

In a simple Ruta project, you need to modify the template analysis engine description (BasicEngine.xml) so that the generated descriptions will contain the parameter value.

Using uimaFIT or other factory methods, you need to pass the parameter and its value when creating the description or analysis engine.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*